# ant scp task hangs on Linux

Tags: linux, ant, jsch

I ran into a problem where an ant scp task hangs during a fileset copy. The task is:

```
<scp file="${usr}:${pwd}@${hst}:${dir}/*" todir="${to}" trust="true"/>
```

It copies a number of files successfully and then hangs.

Note that the host that it's copying from is localhost, but this should make no difference.

I've also used the same ant script to copy files from the same Linux host to a windows machine, and this works without any problems.

Google search reveals that there was a similar problem in around 2007, http://www.symphonious.net/2007/10/23/ant-scpssh-task-hangs-or-never-disconnects/, but the solution of upgrading to latest version of ant (or downgrading jsch) they give doesn't fix the problem for me. (This defect is also metioned in https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41090)

I've used ANT 1.8.2, ANT 1.7.1 and ANT 1.6.5 and they all have this problem.
I'm using jsch 0.1.44, but even with a later version of jsch I get this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Distro and version (of OS and openssh) of the target host? The problem can be at the other end...

Comment: The openssh v3.9p1, openssl 0.9.7a. The distribution is a derivative of RHEL4.8 running Linux kernel 2.6.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround that solves my problem. It's to use sftp="true" attribute of the scp task, like this:

```
<scp file="${usr}:${pwd}@${hst}:${dir}/*" todir="${to}" trust="true" sftp="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I used the option sftp="true" from with a maven-antrun-plugin, I was getting the following error.
[ERROR] around Ant part ...... @: The  type doesn't support the "sftp" attribute.

I was able to get this working by switching back to older version of jsch, specifically 0.1.29

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.29</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: I had similar problem and going back from 0.1.53 to 0.1.29 helped me too. Thanks!